# Http Api request in ASP.NET WebPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I want to make a request using ASP.NET C#. Here is the Documentation of the HTTP API but I am confused with how to send the request. Can you please help me do the Domain Check method, as I am trying but not getting it to work.

```
var auth-id = "123456";
var auth-key= "somerandomstring";
var auth-pass = "password";
var url = ("https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=" + auth_id + &api-key=" + auth_key + "&domain-name=" + domain_name + "&tlds=" + tlds);
```

HTML Form I have Created is like:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="domainName" required />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

After this I submit the `IsPost` function is invoked. Now, how do I pass values?

Now how can I use these parameters to get the JSON result. I have installed the json library from nuget. ASP.NET Web Pages is the technology which is being used.

> Documentation: http://cp.justfhost.com/kb/answer/764

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a WebClient to send the values to the specified Url

```
   var client = new WebClient();
   var stream  = client.OpenRead (url);
   var reader = new StreamReader (stream);
   string json = reader.ReadToEnd ();
   data.Close ();
   reader.Close ();
   // Deserialize json (supposing you are using package Newtonsoft.Json)
   var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

See the samples of Json.NET in http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html and the documentation of WebClient class in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends HTTP Client over other options to consume REST based web services,

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.18

The official samples can be found also on Microsoft sites, such as

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client